# How to use <spring:message> inside an attribute of <form:input>?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I have JSP code like:

```
<div class="formRow">
    <form:input id="email_email" name="email_email" title="XXXXX"/>" path="email" cssClass="input required email" />
    <form:errors path="email" cssClass="error" />
</div>
```

I want to set the `title` attribute with some tooltip text, supporting i18n.  How would I do this?

I am looking to do something like this:

```
<div class="formRow">
    <form:input id="email_email" name="email_email" title="<spring:message code="tooltip.text" />"/>" path="email" cssClass="input required email" />
    <form:errors path="email" cssClass="error" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 81):

```
<spring:message code="tooltip.text" var="variable1"/>
<form:input id="email_email" name="email_email" title="${variable1}" path="email" 
                      cssClass="input required email" />
```

You can't use a tag inside an attribute:
But you can use the above. It works fine.

Comment: Duplicate answers are getting more upvotes. *Facepalm*

Answer (score 27):

You can't use a tag inside a tag, simply. You can do something like this,

```
<spring:message code="tooltip.text" var="i18nTooltip"/> 
<form:input id="email_email" name="email_email" title="${i18nTooltip}" path="email" 
                      cssClass="input required email" />
```

**P.S.** *Better use `${i18nTooltip}`, instead of, `i18nTooltip`, to avoid confusion.*

Comment: Shouldn't title="i18nTooltip" be written as title="${i18nTooltip}"

Comment: @Mushtaq: Both should work. Its a Spring specific tag, the `title` attribute is handled well, both ways, by Spring.

Comment: Thanks Adeel for clarifying, I think data attributes are not supported by spring, hence it not working for me.

Comment: @Mushtaq: Very much possible. However, I believe, you are able to wrap your variable in `${}` to make it work.

Comment: @AdeelAnsari - That is What I did :-)

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the most cleaner way to do it :

```
 <form:input id="email_email" name="email_email" title='<spring:message code="tooltip.text"/>' path="email" cssClass="input required email" />
```

Look for the changed code being, I have removed double qoutes of title attribut to single qoutes and its works wonders.

Comment: This new answer should be more upvoted because you CAN use tags inside attributes. :-)