# JSP exception quote symbol expected

Tags: java, spring, twitter-bootstrap, jsp

I am new to spring MVC, JSP and bootstrap. I am trying to create a sign in form and read the values from it. For this purpose the login.jsp file I wrote is;

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=utf-8"
    pageEncoding="utf-8"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring"%>
<%@taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Bootstrap Form With Spring Mvc Example</title>
<link href="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.js" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <jsp:include page="header.jsp"></jsp:include>

    <div class="container">
        <form:form class="form-signin" method="POST" commandName="user">
            <h2 class="form-signin-heading">
                <spring:message code="main.signin" />
            </h2>
            <label for="email" class="sr-only">
                <spring:message code="main.email" />
            </label> 
            <form:input type="email" path="email" id="email" class="form-control" placeholder=<spring:message code="main.email"/> required autofocus/>

            <label for="password" class="sr-only">
                <spring:message code="main.password" />
            </label> 
            <form:input type="password" path="password" id="password" class="form-control" placeholder=<spring:message code="main.password"/> required/>

            <div class="checkbox">
                <label> <input type="checkbox" id="rememberme">
                    <spring:message code="main.rememberMe" />
                </label>
            </div>
            <input class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" id="submit" value=<spring:message code="main.signinBtn" /> >
        </form:form>
    </div>

    <jsp:include page="footer.jsp"></jsp:include>
</body>
</html>
```

But I get

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [mvc-dispatcher] in context with path [/SpringMVC] threw exception [/WEB-INF/pages/login.jsp (line: 26, column: 86) quote symbol expected] with root cause
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /WEB-INF/pages/login.jsp (line: 26, column: 86) quote symbol expected
```

exception. The line I get this exception is

```
<form:input type="email" path="email" id="email" class="form-control" placeholder=<spring:message code="main.email"/> required autofocus/>
```

I don't have any idea about the problem. Can you help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use `<spring:message>` within `<form:input>` in the manner attempted. Look at this question for the solution: [how-to-use-springmessage-inside-an-attribute-of-forminput](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5273958/how-to-use-springmessage-inside-an-attribute-of-forminput)

Comment: I changed it to 
<spring:message code="main.email" var="email"/> 
   <form:input type="email" path="email" id="email" class="form-control" title="${email}" required autofocus/>
   
but this time it gives "equal symbol expected" exeption :(

Comment: I fixed it. I have deleted "required autofocus".