# How to put <spring:message code="code" /> inside a HTML attribute

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, spring-mvc

I have a form made with **Spring form tag**, with **Bootstrap** that valids the fields.
I have to put the <`spring:message>` tag inside the attribute `data-minlength-error` of **Bootstrap**. Something like this:

```
data-minlength-error="<spring:message code="code"/>"
```

Of course it doesn't work, because of the nested **"**.

I tried editing that code using **'** and \ but I didn't find the right way to make it work.

if I do this: `data-minlength-error='<spring:message code="code" />'`,
Spring show the text **< spring:message code="code" / >** inside the attribute  **data-minlength-error**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May not work as attribute tag.
Please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5273958/how-to-use-springmessage-inside-an-attribute-of-forminput) answer:

This can be a solution:

```
<spring:message code="your.code" var="variable_ref"/>
<input data-minlength-error="${variable_ref}" type="text"/>
```